# Masonry not working with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

Masonry is not working with my dynamic content, I don't know why. I don't think it's a bug on my side, at least I've looked at the code for a few hours now and I can't find anything that isn't working.

```
//reads listbox.php and cycles through the array calling createbox
function listboxs() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '_php/listbox.php',
        success: function (output) {

            var jsonArray = $.parseJSON(output);

            $.each(jsonArray, function (i, box) {
                createbox(box.id, box.name, box.link, box.description, box.tags);
            });
        }
    });
}

//create the code for 1 box
function createbox(id, name, link, description, tags) {

    var boxHtml = "",
        tagsHtml = "",
        descriptionHtml = "";

    boxHtml = '' + '<div class="box" id="' + id + '">' + '<div class="boxinfo">' + '<label class="boxname"><a href="' + link + '" class="boxlink" target="_blank">' + name + '</a></label>';

    $.each(tags, function (i, tag) {
        tagsHtml += '<label class="boxtag">' + ((!tag.name) ? tags[i] : tag.name) + '</label>';
    });

    //if(description.trim().length > 0){
    descriptionHtml = '<textarea class="boxdescription" readonly rows="1">' + description + '</textarea>';
    //}

    boxHtml += tagsHtml + '</div>' + descriptionHtml + '</div>';

    $content.html($content.html() + boxHtml);
}
```

Below is the simplified HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/index.css" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marck+Script' rel='stylesheet'
        type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rosario' rel='stylesheet'
        type='text/css'>
        <script src="_resources/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
        <script src="_resources/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $('#content').masonry();
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content" class="js-masonry"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I know that I don't need the inline javascript calling masonry on content but it's one of my many tests...

Below is part of the CSS:

```
#content{
padding: 15px;
min-height: 400px;
}

/*
################################
box
*/

.box{
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
padding: 5px;
background: #F0F0F0;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.boxinfo{
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.boxname{
font-weight: bold;
}

.boxdescription{
border: none;
outline: none;
background: white;
overflow: hidden;
}

.boxtag{
margin-left: 5px;
}

#boxdecoy{
height: 45px;
}

.boxname, .boxtag, .boxdescription{
font-family: 'Rosario', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
}

.boxlink{
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

.boxlink:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I'm really going crazy with all of it because I tested creating boxes by hand (this means writting in the html) in content, and if i do masonry works fine. If i create them through the function that you see there it doesn't work... i call listboxs right in the begining of the javascript file after I declare all my vars...

Hope I was clear and you can help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `appended` method. From [docs](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#appended):

> Add and lay out newly appended item elements.

Look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FuZC7/1/)

Try to change your code to

```
boxHtml += tagsHtml +
        '</div>' +
    descriptionHtml +
'</div>';

var $boxHtml = $(boxHtml);

$content.append($boxHtml).masonry('appended', $boxHtml);
```

Comment: This did work, however masonry doesn't really seem to be applied correctly I guess. The divs aren't correctly placed, they are slightly on top of each other. I've tested applying $content.masonry() to the action Click of a button and then it places them correctly. Any idea? I also placed a $content.masonry() after the each cycle in listBoxs() and nothing happens. Hilariously if I simply zoom in/out on my page then it places the divs correctly.

Comment: Do you have images in your boxes or may be you applies some java-script transformation (like uniform etc) on them? Masonry uses absolute positioning based on the item size. So if size slightly changes it cause overlaps. Read more [here](http://masonry.desandro.com/faq.html#overlapping).

Answer (score 1):

Adding up to Grin's answer:

You should also apply data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 200, "itemSelector": ".item" }' to your #container.

```
<div id="content" class="js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 200, "itemSelector": ".item" }'></div>
```

Like so. It might help with your comment response. I don't have the rep to answer as a comment.

Comment: That did seem to work, but if I change the width to say 50 it still works, however 60 doesn't. Masonry is acting really weird, thanks though.