# Ajax appended elements won't fall in line with like elements positioned by masonry.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on this blog here:
http://insights.signetaccel.com/blog

The blog summaries on this listing page are positioned using a script called masonry.js. The container for the summaries is ".grid", while the summaries are all classed ".grid-item".

I have another script that creates an infinity scroll effect which requests the url to the next page, finds all of the .grid-items, and appends them to the bottom of the .grid container on the page.

The issue is that the masonry.js script applies inline styling to the .grid-item divs to position them. The newly appended .grid-item divs aren't effected by masonry.js because they are appended after the page loads.

how can I get the masonry.js script to "re-apply" itself to the page after appending new elements in order to have it apply to these new elements?

infinity scroll Script

```
(function($) {
$.fn.swoosh=function(loadingImgUrl,callback){
    if(!loadingImgUrl){
        loadingImgUrl="Loading...";
    }
    if (callback==null){
        callback=-1;
    }
    var postList=this;

    //SET VARIABLES
    var turnOff=false;
    var pageNumber=2;                                                    //toggle switch for infinite scroll.  shuts off when on last page    
    var urlArray=window.location.href.toString().split("/");                                //the array of url sections
    var blogUrl=urlArray[0]+"//"+urlArray[2]+"/"+urlArray[3]+"/";                       //the url for the blog
    var baseUrl=blogUrl+"page/";                                        //URL with the page number stripped off the end
    var postUrl="";                                                         //initialize postURL string                                                       
    var processing = false;                                                 //tells the scripts if there is already an ajax load happening

    //insert the loading bar at the end of the posts-list
    if(loadingImgUrl!="Loading..."){
        postList.parent().append('<div class="loading"><img src="'+loadingImgUrl+'"></div>');
    }
    else{
        postList.parent().append('<div class="loading">'+loadingImgUrl+'</div>');
    }
    $(".loading").hide();   //make sure loading bar is hidden

    $(document).scroll(function(){

        //kick out of function if it's already running, if it has been shut off, or if there is no 2nd page
        if (processing || turnOff || pageNumber==0){
            return false;
        }
        //when scrolling gets to the footer, start chugging!
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(".footer-container-wrapper").height()-150){
            processing = true;
                                                        //currently processessing, so don't call function again until done
            $(".loading").fadeIn(200);                  //fade in loading bar

            postUrl=baseUrl + pageNumber;               //calculate the page to load


            //AJAX CALL
            $.get(postUrl, function(data){
                //grab only post items from the loaded page
                var posts=$(data).find(".grid-item");

                //check that the loaded page has content
                if (posts.length > 0){
                    console.log(loadingImgUrl);
                    //fade out the loading bar, then attach the new items to the end of the list
                    $(".loading").fadeOut(200,function(){
                        posts.appendTo(".grid");

                        console.log(posts);

                    });
                    pageNumber++;                       //increment the page to load.
                    $(".next-posts-link").attr("href",baseUrl+pageNumber);

                }
                //if the loaded page doesn't have content, it means we have reached the end.
                else{

                    turnOff=true;
                    $(".next-posts-link").after('<div class="next-posts-link unactive">Next</div>');
                    $(".next-posts-link:not(.unactive)").remove();
                    $(".loading").fadeOut(200);
                }
                processing=false;                   //we are done processing, so set up for the next time
                setTimeout(function(){
                    twttr.widgets.load();
                    IN.parse();
                    FB.XFBML.parse();
                    gapi.plusone.go();
                     },350);
                 });  
             }
         });
     };
 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: You should rebind `Masonry` after `$.post` success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `rebind` `masonry` after `$.post` after `posts.appendTo(".grid");`

```
//take your binding in a variable
var container =  $('.grid').masonry({
            // options
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            columnWidth: 200,
            columnWidth: '.grid-item',
            percentPosition: true
        });   

//do this on $.post  
$(".loading").fadeOut(200,function(){
      posts.appendTo(".grid");    
      console.log(posts);
       //changes made here in your code
       container.append(posts).masonry('appended', posts);
});
```

Comment: as far as I can tell that didn't work for me. Perhaps I did it wrong. Could you show me what it should look like?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought you meant. It doesn't work for some reason though.

Comment: it isn't applying the inline styling from the masonry.js script to the appended .grid-item divs.

Comment: @JSum what you are getting in `console.log(posts);`? It should have `class` `grid-item` in html.

Comment: Yes. You can see if you check the page. Once you scroll down posts contains 6 grid-items from the next page. The items are placed at the top of .grid behind the first set of posts because the first set of posts are absolute positioned by masonry.js and the appended .grid-items aren't

Comment: I found solution. You have to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476102/masonry-not-working-with-dynamic-content?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: You have "content" where you should have container. Other than that it worked! thanks for the awesome fix. your a life saver!

Comment: @JSum Ok i have fixed that.